# Inserting into many-to-many table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my `Tag` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tag](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [CreationDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [TagSlug] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

and this is my `Post` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Post](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](400) NOT NULL,
    [Body] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Summary] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [CreationDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UrlSlug] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Picture] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [TagId] [int] NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Post]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Post_Tag] FOREIGN KEY([TagId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Tag] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Post] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Post_Tag]
GO
```

I just wanna to insert the `Id` from `Tag` and `PostId` from `Post` into a new table named `Post_Tag` which is a many to many relation, this is the script of my `Post_Tag` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Post_Tag](
    [PostId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TagId] [int] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Post_Tag] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PostId] ASC, [TagId] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Post_Tag]  WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Post_Tag_dbo.Post_PostId] 
FOREIGN KEY([PostId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Post] ([Id])
   ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Post_Tag] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Post_Tag_dbo.Post_PostId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Post_Tag] WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Post_Tag_dbo.Tag_TagId] 
FOREIGN KEY([TagId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Tag] ([Id])
   ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Post_Tag] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Post_Tag_dbo.Tag_TagId]
GO
```

Now, to do that I've tried the below query:

```
insert into [Blog].[dbo].[Post_Tag] (PostId,TagId)
   select [Id] as [PostId] from [OldBlog].[dbo].[Tag]
   select [TagId] from [OldBlog].[dbo].[Post]
```

but this error appear while running the script:

> The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.

what's wrong with my query? thanks

Comment: Tables in SQL are all about relationships between entities.  How are entries supposed to be related?  There's a `tagId` column in the old `post` table, can you just use that?

Comment: sorry I didn't mention this, I've migrated the first script to second. I've migrated a one-to-many relation to many-to-many relation and deleted the TagId in Post table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2 select queries are being processed separately. You will have to come up with a way to join `[OldBlog].[dbo].[Tag]` to `[OldBlog].[dbo].[Post]` so you can insert fields `PostId,TagId` into `[Blog].[dbo].[Post_Tag]` from this new table expression.

Answer (score 2):

For this, you can use the row number of each row from the two select statements as a link so you can join them and select what you need from both of them.

```
SELECT POST.[PostId], TAG.[TagId]
FROM (
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Id])  AS Link, [Id] as [PostId] from [OldBlog].[dbo].[Tag]) AS POST
JOIN (
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [TagId]) AS Link, [TagId] from [OldBlog].[dbo].[Post]) AS TAG ON POST.Link = TAG.Link
```

IMPORTANT NOTE:
This is just a means of "forcing" a relationship between tables without any relationship to each other whatsoever. This is indeed a dangerous thing to do because we are forcing a relationship between the tables based on row number and not an actual key. This should only be used if there is no definite expected output or as a last resort if there is no other way to link two or more unrelated tables where the relationship of each selected column don't matter.

Comment: ...I find this dangerous.  I know the OP didn't list criteria for what's to be expected, but this is assembling a relationship that may not be there.  You at least need to explain what you're doing and the possible problem in the approach.  This _is_ a potentially valid answer, though (and more useful than the earlier one, if correct)

Comment: I just run this query and it was successful too, thanks

Comment: This is just a means of "forcing" a relationship between tables without any relationship to each other whatsoever. This is indeed a dangerous thing to do because we are forcing a relationship between the tables based on row number and not an actual key. This should only be used if there is no definite expected output or as a last resort if there is no other way to link two or more unrelated tables where the relationship of each selected column don't matter.

Comment: @SQL_wiz - That needs to be put into the actual answer.  But yes, that should work.